# How to populate a text field in a form with line breaks in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield, line-breaks

I have a text field in a Rails form that I want to display with strings with line breaks.  For some reason, I cannot get Rails to show them on separate lines.  Here is the code in the edit action of my controller:

```
def edit
    @billing_log = BillingLog.find(params[:id])
    team_comments = ""
    @billing_log.billable_totals.each do |billable_total|
      team_comments += (billable_total.user_name + ' - ' + billable_total.comments + '\n')
    end
    @billing_log.team_notes = team_comments
end
```

And here is the snippet from the form.

```
  = simple_form_for @billing_log do |f|
    .row
      .span8
        = f.input :team_notes, :as => :text, :input_html => { :class => 'input-block-level', :rows => '6' }
```

I cannot get the text to display with each comment on a separate line in the text field.  Instead, they show with '\n',e.g.,

```
First Comment\nSecond Comment
```

I would like them to appear as:

```
First Comment
Second Comment
```

I have tried substituting

```
'<br/>'
```

instead of

```
'\n'
```

in my code for the edit method as shown below:

```
  team_comments += (billable_total.user_name + ' - ' + billable_total.comments + '<br/>')
```

But that does not work either.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Instead of `'<br/>'` did you try `'&#10;'`?

Answer (score 0):

When using HTML tags, just make sure the ruby string gets appended with `.html_safe` *unless* the string has the possibility to be `nil`. If is can be `nil`, then wrap the string and prepend with`raw()`

So in your case, either

```
(billable_total.user_name + ' - ' + billable_total.comments + '<br/>').html_safe
```

or

```
raw(billable_total.user_name + ' - ' + billable_total.comments + '<br/>')
```

You also do `not` need to end your `br` tag with a blackslash `/`, so just use `<br>` - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Comment: I wish it was that simple :(.  html_safe method does not do anything.  Also raw is not allowed in the controller code.  I can and have used raw extensively in the "show" type of rails pages but not on an "input" type of form control.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put line breaks in a text field (which is what an input helper generates).  You should use a text_area helper instead.

Comment: This is using simple_form gem.  The f.input :team_notes, :as => :text statement generates "text_area" type html input instead :)

Comment: Ah I see, I beg your pardon :)

Comment: No problem Max.  Thanks for trying to help though :)